# How to add 'add-in' button to show pop-up window in outlook home menu?

Tags: outlook, ribbonx

Is there any way to add a button in home menu of outlook app?
If I click a button, I want a particular website to appear as a pop-up window.

Any comments would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

VBA doesn't allow customizing the Fluent UI in Outlook. To customize the ribbon UI in Outlook you need to develop an add-in.

A rich customization is available for COM based add-ins, see [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022) to get started quickly. You may find the [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2022) helpful.

Another possible route is web-based add-ins. See [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook) for more information. There is no so much flexibility like with COM add-ins, but the solution allows to support multiple platforms - Web, Mac OS, Windows.